# Remove 2 or less linebreaks

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

How would I use str_replace to find every ending square bracket ']' and remove 2 or less linebreaks from the end. So, if there were 1 or 2 line breaks after ] it'd remove all. If there were 3 you'd end up with 1 after the ]. 4 you'd end up with 2 after etc.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned `str_replace`, I assume that you are using PHP (you should add a tag for that if this is the case!). And since you tagged regular expressions you might want to use `preg_replace` instead. This should work rather platform-independently then:

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/\](?:\r\n|\n|\r){1,2}/', ']', $str);
```

where `$str` is obviously your original string.

Note that the `]` gets escaped, because it's a special regex character (used for character classes). The round brackets just contain a list of all possible linebreaks. The `?:` is optional and more relevant for complex regular expressions where you need to access captured subpatterns (in fact the `?:` says, don't match this subpattern, because I don't need it). And the `{1,2}` simply says, match one or two of those. And since regular expressions are greedy by default, it will take two if it can.

**EDIT:** One more thought. You could solve this with `str_replace`, but not so well in one go for all possible linebreaks (because `str_replace` doesn't support alternatives). [This example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#example-4554) might give you an idea.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude cases where the last bracket is part of a '[/h1]' sequence?

Comment: [Yes, it's called negative lookbehind.](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) For example: '/(?<!\[\/h1)\](?:\r\n|\n|\r){1,2}/'. Note again, that I have to escape both `[` and `/` (because it's the delimiter I chose).

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. Once I played around with this - I realized that what I am really trying to do is. If its a '[/h1]' I need 1-3 \n removed. If its any other ']' i need 1-2 \n removed. I managed to do it with a lot of code... but is there an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

[**str_replace**](http://uk.php.net/str_replace),

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

doesn't support regular expressions, what you want is [**preg_replace**](http://uk.php.net/preg_replace)

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

with a pattern like `'/\](?:\r\n|\n|\r){0,2}/'` and replace of `']'`